# i want to inline this function how can i do this with dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to inline this function to return a list of string to be more clean

```
List<String> suraName(StudentLevelLessonsModel studentLevelLessonsModel) {
  List<String> stringList = [];
  for (var element in studentLevelLessonsModel.data!.lessons!) {
    stringList.add(element.name!);
  }
  return stringList;
}
```

`studentLevelLessonsModel.data!.lessons.(some thing here to return list of string)`

Comment: please add more info about `StudentLevelLessonsModel`. better add relevant parts from class definition.

Comment: You've told us what you want to do, but haven't actually asked a question

Comment: you may like to use `.map((e)=> e).toList()`

Comment: i want to return list of string  (studentLevelLessonsModel.data!.lessons![index].name) i can do it by function that's return list of strings but i want to inline this function

Comment: for any inline function do `(){yourOperation}()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I want

```
 studentLevelLessonsModel.data!.lessons!.map((e) => e.name!).toList()
```